# how to access files in s3 bucket for other commands using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to use some commands with the aws cli on large files that are stored in a s3 bucket without copying the files to the local directory
(I'm familiar with the aws **cp** command, it's not what I want).

For example, let's say I want to use a simple bash commands like "head" or "more".
If I try to use it like this:

`head s3://bucketname/file.txt`

but then I get:

*head: cannot open ‘s3://bucketname/file.txt’ for reading: No such file or directory*
How else can I do it?

How else can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that. You need to download the files to your local file system first in order to perform local commands on them like `head`.

Comment: You can do something like `aws s3 cp s3://whatever/ - | more`, or use `aws s3 presign s3://whatever/` and then `curl -s "URL" | more`, or install [s3fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to do this in the background for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wether a command will be able to access a file over s3 bucket or not depends entirely on the command. Under the hood, every command is just a program. When you run something like `head filename`, the argument `filename` is passed as an argument to the head command's main() function. You can check out the source code here: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/head.c

Essentially, since the head command does not support S3 URIs, you cannot do this. You can either:

1. Copy the s3 file to stdout and then pipe it to head: `aws s3 cp fileanme - | head`. This doesn't seem the likely option if file is too big for the pipe buffer.
2. Use s3curl to copy a range of bytes: [how to access files in s3 bucket for other commands using cli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72659365/6502671)